# Handlebars in Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, content-builder

Can I use handlebars in Content Builder to pull personalization data from multiple data extensions?

Example:
{{Contacts.Attributes.DataExtension.Field}}

Or does this only work on the backend working with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it with Guided Template Language. If you just want to access personalisation within the send data extension, eg first name, you could use {{first name}}

Comment: Thanks unfortunately I am pulling from a separate data extension, I am curretrnly using Amp script. How do I go about displaying the lookup Value? Here is what I got
`%%[
VAR @var, @this
SET @this = [Subscriber_Key]
SET @var = Lookup ("leads", "favorite_car", "Subscriber_Key, @this)
]%%`

Comment: You have set the value as @var. You can display that value with %%=v(@var)=%%